# My children are missing Fork dup2 and execvp problems

Tags: c, fork, execvp, dup2

This code is supposed to read in

```
conc ls -l /bin > Dout/concBin.txt , ls -l /usr/bin > Dout/concUsrBin.txt , ls -l /etc > Dout/concEtc.txt
```

and then print out the ppid it is supposed to redirect after forking but before execing. currently it is reading in most of the files, but it prints out the bin (the example prints only the > , < and file names and PPID) It only seems to generate concbin.txt to the Dout directory and then doesn't generate any other files. I think something is messed up with my for loop and my execvp.
I apologize ahead of time for the mass of code. my professor provided a header file and a main file, those are working fine with my code. The stdin, stdout error checking printfs I put in are working so I am totally lost. I think I am not making enough children with my for loop in Argv

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include "cs3423p8.h"
int concCmd (Cmd cmdM[], int iCmdCnt, Token tokenM[], int iTokenCnt);
//int pipeCmd (Cmd cmdM[], int iCmdCnt, Token tokenM[], int iTokenCnt);

//prints parents processID Child's ProcessID, the Command and Command arguments
//fork each of the children, Max commands is 5. If any of the commands is redirect or output
//do redirection after forking but before execing
 //redirect stdout for each child, and execvp to the particular command for child
int concCmd (Cmd cmdM[], int iCmdCnt, Token tokenM[], int iTokenCnt)
{
     int j;
     int i;
     int count = 0;
     long lForkPid;
     long lWaitPid;
     int iExitStatus = 0;
     char *execArgv[25];
     int fdin, fdout;
     //make children
     lForkPid = fork();
     //children made
     for(i = 0; i < iCmdCnt; i++)
     {             
     //count =0;
         switch(lForkPid)
         {
             case -1:
             errExit("fork failed: %s", strerror(errno));
             break;
             case 0://child

             execArgv[0] = cmdM[i].szCmdNm;
             //count = 0;
             for(j = cmdM[i].iBeginIdx; j <= cmdM[i].iEndIdx; j++)             
                 {

                     execArgv[count + 1] = tokenM[j];
                     count++;
                 }
                     execArgv[count] = NULL;

                     if (cmdM[i].iStdinRedirectIdx !=0)
                 {
                     printf("stdin redirect \n \n ");

                     fdin = open(tokenM[cmdM[i].iStdinRedirectIdx], O_RDONLY);
                     dup2(fdin, STDIN_FILENO);
                     close(fdin);
                     fprintf(stderr,"sTDIN REDIRECT Child Process: PID=%ld, PPID=%ld\n" , (long) getpid(), (long) getppid());
                     // execvp(cmdM[i].szCmdNm, execArgv);
                     //errExit("Child process failed to exec: %s", strerror(errno));
                  }

                  if (cmdM[i].iStdoutRedirectIdx !=0)
                  {
                      printf("stdout redirect \n\n");

                      fdout = open(tokenM[cmdM[i].iStdoutRedirectIdx], O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IWGRP);
                      dup2(fdout, STDOUT_FILENO);
                      close(fdout);
                      fprintf(stderr, "sTDOUT REDIRECT Child Process: PID=%ld, PPID=%ld\n", (long) getpid(), (long) getppid());

                  }
                  execvp(cmdM[i].szCmdNm, execArgv);
                  //errExit("Child process failed to exec: %s", strerror(errno));


                 // exit(0);
              default://parent
                  lWaitPid = wait(&iExitStatus);
                     // if(lWaitPid == -1)
                     // errExit("wait error: %s", strerror(errno));
             }
        }
         return 0;
     }
```

Comment: I was going to ask this question yesterday. Are you sure `tokenM[cmdM[i].iStdoutRedirectIdx]` is different while `i` increases. I.e. are you sure the value of `cmdM[i].iStdoutRedirectIdx` is gonna changes along with `i` changes

Comment: I was not sure what to put in open(), to be honest the tutor added the loops. I'm not sure he knows how to write this.

Comment: You were right. You indeed created one child only. Review your code, the fork() is called only one time. How many children do you expect with only one fork() call. You should put the fork() into the for loop. And further more, if you want child processes are executed concurrently, you'd better move wait() call out of the for loop. And if you move wait() out of for loop, remember you can't just call it once, which is not enough.